# How to force JPA(eclipselink) to use joins instead of independent queries?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm using JPA 2 in my project (eclipselink provider), and I have the following problem:

When I execute the following code:

```
em.createQuery("select t from " + entityName  + " t where t.id = ?1"
).setParameter(1, id)
.setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH, HintValues.TRUE)
.setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH_CASCADE, CascadePolicy.CascadeAllParts)
.getSingleResult();
```

JPA generates tons of queries to fetch all dependent objects( i.e ~90 queries to fetch an entity).
It there any way to force JPA to use joins instead of independent queries?

Answer (score 4):

You can use join fetching or batch fetching to optimize relationships.  Also you should use LAZY on your relationships to avoid loading them when not required.

See,
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html

Answer (score 2):

In your query you can use `join` and `fetch` to construct the query yourself.

So for example if your entity t has a

```
@OneToMany public List<RelatedEntity> things;
```

then your query can use:

```
select t from entityName t join fetch t.things where t.id = ?1
```

Read the documentation for JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language).